# Rendering web page in IFrame without src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to render a webpage, say `http://www.google.com`, in an iFrame without using the `src` attribute of iFrame.
Is there any possibility to do this, because I have seen such implementation on other sites. I want to achieve this to decrease the security threat on the site.

Comment: Why do you think the `src` attribute causes a security threat?

Comment: You could create an empty `iframe` and then update the `src` attribute via JS... But an `iframe` expects either a `src` or `srcdoc` attribute in order to display content.

Comment: Would you be able to provide such example as you mentioned that you have seen such implementations please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below minor jQuery code to temporary hide the iFrame code and upon document ready, can load the SRC of the iFrame.

However, since we are exposing the source of the iFrame to public users, someone will however crack the SRC by checking inspect element or network tab. Still, you can use below code as per your question request:

**HTML**:

```
<iframe id="mySuperSecretSRC" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

**jQuery**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#mySuperSecretSRC").attr("src", "The URL which you wanted to hide");
});
```

Let us know if any more help needed. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AHanny please mark it if you feel it has helped.